# Passing Observable with specified generic List type as method argument

Tags: java, generics, rx-java, generic-programming

I can write a method that accepts a `List`, the elements of which extend a given base class, like this:

```
class BaseClass { }
class SubClass extends BaseClass { }

static void listMethod(List<? extends BaseClass> list) { }
```

Calling this method is straightforward, and works as expected:

```
    List<BaseClass> b = Collections.empty();
    List<SubClass> s = Collections.empty();

    listMethod(b);  // ok
    listMethod(s);  // ok
```

Now I would like to change my method such that it accepts not a `List`, but instead an `Observable` that emits a `List`. The signature thus changes to be:

```
static void observableListMethod(Observable<List<? extends BaseClass>> listObservable) { }
```

Unfortunately, attempts to call this new method result in argument mismatch errors of the form:

> `Observable<List<BaseClass>> cannot be converted to Observable<List<? extends BaseClass>>`

Unlike the general issue of [dealing with generic collections in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po), the issue here does not seem to be an incorrect assumption casting between subclass and baseclass collections. Rather it seems to have more to do with the specific type of the Observable being used.

```
    Observable<List<BaseClass>> b = Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());
    Observable<List<SubClass>> s = Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());

    observableListMethod(b);    // argument mismatch / incompatible types
    observableListMethod(s);    // argument mismatch / incompatible types

    // I can map the List to a read-only variant...
    observableListMethod(b.map(Collections::unmodifiableList)); // ok (for readonly)
    observableListMethod(s.map(Collections::unmodifiableList)); // ok (for readonly)
```

The best solution I've come up with so far is to change the method signature to specify `BaseClass` specifically (not `? extends BaseClass`), and then do some ugly `List` unpacking and casting using Rx:

```
static void observableListMethod2(Observable<List<BaseClass>> listObservable) { }
public static void callObservableListMethod2() {
    Observable<List<BaseClass>> b = Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());
    Observable<List<SubClass>> s = Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());

    observableListMethod2(b);    // ok
    observableListMethod2(s.flatMapIterable(it -> it).cast(BaseClass.class).toList()); // ok, but yuck!
}
```

Surely there is a cleaner way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Use `Observable<? extends List<? extends BaseClass>>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Comment: @4castle I don't believe this is a duplicate question to the one referenced, at least not in an obvious way. I understand the basic tripfalls often encountered using generic collections, my issue here is understanding why the common solution for dealing with typed collections doesn't extend directly to an Observable case.

Comment: I've removed my close vote but I'll leave the link there for reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other answer shows you can solve this by using a type variable. But to explain what's happening;

```
static void observableListMethod(Observable<List<? extends BaseClass>> listObservable) { }
```

Requires an `Observable<List<? extends BaseClass>>` as a parameter. In other words it takes an `Observable<T>` where `T` is `List<? extends BaseClass>>`.

Now, you try to pass a `Observable<List<BaseClass>>` for instance, i.e. an `Observable<U>` where `U` is `List<BaseClass>`, a *different* type than `T`. But since [generics are invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265) you can not assign an `Observable<U>` to an `Observable<T>`. Even if `U` is assignable to `T`.

To make it work, you'd need `Observable<? extends T>` as a parameter. If you then substitute `T` for `List<? extends BaseClass>>` again you get:

```
Observable<? extends List<? extends BaseClass>>
```

If you make that the parameter type this should compile:

```
Observable<List<BaseClass>> b = Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());
Observable<List<SubClass>> s = Observable.just(Collections.emptyList());

observableListMethod(b);
observableListMethod(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems this could be a workaround:

```
static <T extends BaseClass> void observableListMethod(Observable<List<T>> listObservable)
```

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but at least that one is compiling for me.

Comment: yeah, me too.. xD

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? In the case of `b` `T` is inferred to `BaseClass`, and in the case of `s` it is inferred to `SubClass`.